# non-static method loadUrl(String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, onesignal, create-react-native-app

```
WebView.loadUrl(additionalData.optString("targeturl"));
```

how to debug error non-static method loadUrl(String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory, you should call loadUrl on an instance of WebView, it's not a static method, therefore you can't call it statically on the class like you're doing.

e.g.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

also, check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview)